# discord.js get channelid by reaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to get the channel id by reacting to a message in the channel where I want to get the channel id?

Example:
I press on a reaction in a channel, the bot logs the channel ID of the channel where I reacted to a msg in the console.

Comment: happen to have a code sample for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the awaitReactions method, although you must supply a timeout parameter for that method which is not something I'd recommend setting as a large value.

```js
message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => (reaction.emoji.name == ''), {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000
}).then(collected => {
    // Collected is an array of emojis.
    console.log('Thumbs up emoji detected in: ', message.channel.id)
}).catch(() => {
    message.reply('No reaction after 30 seconds, operation canceled');
});
```

Here's a full article about awaiting messages and emojis: https://maah.gitbooks.io/discord-bots/content/getting-started/awaiting-messages-and-reactions.html